# How can I resolve conflicting support library version?

Tags: flutter

I'm making a flutter app.
I'm trying to use two plugins.

- image_picker: 0.4.10
- firebase_storage: 1.0.3

But I got this error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

I understood It is a dependencies problem.
But these dependencies are written in plugin's build.gradle.
So if I fix the version string now, when I update plugin I will have same problem every time.

Do you know any good solution?

Thank you.

Comment: try using this workaround : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020

Comment: @diegoveloper That's the answer! Thank you very much.